# Show that $0\le 1- \frac{n!}{(n-k)!n^k}\le1$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

I would like to prove that 
$$
0\le 1- \frac{n!}{(n-k)!n^k}\le1
$$
for $n\ge k \in \mathbb{N}$

I tried to use the fact that $n^k\ge n$ and binomial coefficient but it doesn't look good, plus I have other ideas (like Stirling) but I think it's inappropriate.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly, $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!n^k} \gt 0$, so the upper bound follows immediately.

What remains is to show that $n! \le (n-k)!n^k$.  This is also easily seen, given that:
$$\begin{align}
n! &= \underbrace{n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots}_{k \text{ numbers}}\underbrace{(n-k)(n-k-1)\cdots 2\cdot 1}_{(n-k)!} \\
&\le \underbrace{n\cdot n\cdot n\cdots}_{k \text{ numbers}}\underbrace{(n-k)(n-k-1)\cdots 2\cdot 1}_{(n-k)!} \\
&\le n^k\cdot(n-k)! \\
\end{align}$$

Since the denominator is greater than the numerator, the fraction is less than $1$.  This shows the lower bound.

Answer (score 1):

$n!=n(n-1)(n-2)\dots[(n-k)!]\leq n^k(n-k)!$